# Excel Icon sets

Tags: excel

How can I used icon sets to change colors or add flags based on the cell above the one I want to change the color to, i.e if I have from cell A1 to A10 I want if A2 is larger than A1 to be written on Green color and if it is equal to it be be written on yellow color and if A2 is less than A1 to be written on Red color and if the number in cell A3 is less then the number on cell A2 to be written on red and if equal to be on yellow and if A3 is more than A2 to be written on green and also if number on cell A4 equal to number in cell A3 be written on yellow and so on till cell A10 an I compare it with A9 and I want to do this with Icon sets Please

Comment: in LibreOffice it's called "Conditional Formatting"

Answer (score 0):

In Excel it's also called "Conditional Formatting". I think this article: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx is enough informative.

The only thing you have to do is to set correct condition